# If my Windows VPS has multiple IP addresses and I want to use them as SOCKS proxy servers, what software do you recommend?

Tags: networking, proxy

My application uses multiple connections, and I want them to be routed through different IP addresses. My VPS provider has already provided two additional IPs. My idea is for the server to listen on multiple ports, and if it receives a packet on port 8081, forward it to IP1, if it receives a packet on port 8082, forward it to IP2, and so on. How can I achieve this with limited networking knowledge? My app can utilize HTTPS, Socks4, and Socks5 proxies.

I have tried nginx, and it can handle HTTPS, but it also requires a certificate and key file, which I don't have.

I have tried WinGate, but after rebooting my VPS following the installation, I couldn't access my VPS.